# How can I implement a scheduled message for my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a discord bot in python that sends a screenshot of my weekly university schedule. It currently works if you summon it with the "!" prefix, but now I want it to execute the same schedule sending function by itself every sunday at 3PM.

Here is the current code that works with the "!" prefix

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pyautogui
import datetime
from datetime import date
import schedule

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

BOT_TOKEN = "token"

my_date = datetime.date.today() 
year, week_num, day_of_week = my_date.isocalendar()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is alive")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) 

@bot.command()
async def schema1(ctx, classid="myclassname"):
    #channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('school.com') 
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000, 440, duration = 1)
    pyautogui.click(1000, 440)                
    pyautogui.typewrite(classid)             
    pyautogui.typewrite(["enter"])
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)") 
    time.sleep(2)
    await ctx.send(f"Schedule week {week_num} for {classid}")
    driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('screenshot.png'))
bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

I have tried implementing my current code with the "schedule" import, but the bot doesn't send the screenshot nor the message anymore. Im not very experienced in python so any suggestions are welcome.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pyautogui
import datetime
from datetime import date
import schedule
import sys
import tracemalloc

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

BOT_TOKEN = ""

my_date = datetime.date.today() 
year, week_num, day_of_week = my_date.isocalendar()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is alive")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

async def continuation(ctxx):
    await ctxx.send(f"Schedule week {week_num} for class")
    await ctxx.send(file=discord.File('screenshot.png')) 

def job():
    channel = bot.get_channel()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('school.com') 
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000, 440, duration = 1)
    pyautogui.click(1000, 440)                
    pyautogui.typewrite("classname")             
    pyautogui.typewrite(["enter"])
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)") 
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
    continuation(channel)   
    print("Job done")    
    #driver.quit()

schedule.every().sunday.at("15:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) extension from discord.py. This module allows you to easily create loops that run at a certain time of day.
After creating a loop that runs every day at 3 PM, you only need to find out when is sunday.
Here's an simple example of a loop that runs every Sunday at 3 PM (UTC):

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import datetime


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())


# creating a loop that runs every day at 3 PM UTC
@tasks.loop(time=datetime.time(hour=15, minute=0))
async def job_loop():
    weekday = datetime.datetime.utcnow().weekday()
    if weekday == 6:    # sunday
        # do your job here
        await job()


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # you need to start the loop
    if not job_loop.is_running():
        job_loop.start()


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: This did the trick! Do you also know how I can keep the current week number up to date  every time the message is sent (so once a week). My current implementation using datetime today, to my knowledge, creates a constant and that is why it isnt updated.

Comment: You can do like I did. Just call `datetime.datetetime.utcnow().weekday()` to get the updated day of the week.
Or do you want to get the week number in relation to the weeks in the month? For example, first week, second week, third week, fourth week, fifth week?

Comment: I want to get the number of the current week, ie right now it is week 23. I have been getting this with the datetime isocalendar and storing it in a const (?) that's called week_num, see my most upper code for reference.